# How to move a CakePHP App to a production Server?

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Hello Everyone I hope you guys can help me. Today I need to upload a project I created in CakePHP using **Xampp on Windows** to a production server basically what I tried is to upload all files through ftp and I changed the database name and user name to the productions server heres a [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceIHQ.png) but when I visit the site I get an Internal Server Error message. Here is the [error.log](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/03dpww0n3yzhvsy/error.log) from CakePHP 3.x

I need this for a important school project, I hope you guys can help me.

Comment: what does the logging say? set debug to true and what does the error say now? we cant just guess what is wrong there

Comment: Thanks the problem is when I upload the files I can't debug it because I get an **HTTP ERROR 500** when visiting the site

Comment: if you set debug: true in Config/app.php your errors will tell you alot more then just 500 error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you move CakePHP code on server.After code uploaded on server you have to take care of below things.

**For CakePHP v 2.x**

Make Sure your database connection and configuration is correctly mentioned in app/Config/core.php file and set **debug: 0**.

Delete cache directories, **app/tmp/cache/models**, **app/tmp/cache/views**  and **app/tmp/cache/persistance**.

**For CakePHP v 3.x**

Make Sure your database connection and configuration is correctly mentioned in Config/app.php file and set **debug: false**.

Delete cache directories, **tmp/cache/models** and **tmp/cahe/persistance**.

Comment: Thank you very much will try it out now :) I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I reuploaded it and checked the settings you gave me above but it still doesn't wok all I get is a **HTTP ERROR 500**

Comment: Which version of  CakePHP you are using?

If its 2.x Can you check logs in app/tmp/logs/error.log

If its 3.x Can you check logs in logs/error.log

Also try with enable debug mode as developement

Comment: sure here is the error log https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/03dpww0n3yzhvsy/error.log btw I'm using CakePHP 3.x

Comment: Ahh, please give 777 permission in server for tmp folder with sub folder recursivly. Your log file seems your localhost logs file.

Comment: `Error: [TypeError] Argument 1 passed to App\Controller\UsersController::beforeFilter() must be an instance of App\Controller\Event, instance of Cake\Event\Event given`, `Error: [ParseError] syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting end of file` - This answer appears to have no bearing on the problem. @Dexo your log output should be [in the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38425989/edit).

Comment: which version of PHP you are using in localhost and in server?

Comment: Please check "use Cake\Event\Event;" is written in your UsersController.php or not? 

If its not then please add this line after namespace statement.

Comment: Hey, I have a problem with the routing of my application. The start page renders perfectly, but no other page or link can be found on the server. I always get the response: "Not Found - The requested URL /test was not found on this server.". Is anyone of you still in the topic and can tell me what the issue could be?